# How to find maximum avg

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display the maximum average salary; however, I can't seem to get it to work.

I can get a list of the average salaries to display with:

```
select worker_id, avg(salary)
from workers
group by worker_id;
```

However, when I try to display a list of the maximum average salary with:

```
select max (avg(salary))
from (select worker_id, avg(salary)
      from workers
      group by worker_id);
```

it doesn't run. I get an "invalid identifier" error. How do I use the average salary for each worker to find the maximum average for each worker?

Thanks.

Comment: I would expect a column called WORKER_ID to be the primary key for a table called WORKERS.  If so, the AVG() salary would be the average for the whole table, and the MAX(AVG()) salary would just be the AVG() salary.   However, I suspect it's just a shonky data model.

Comment: Another possibility is that the key for the table is a combination of worker_id and date - if so, a weighted average by number of days may be more useful than a simple arithmetic average.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Columns resulting from aggregate functions (e.g. avg) usually get arbitrary names. Just use an alias for it, and select on that:

```
select max(avg_salary)
from (select worker_id, avg(salary) AS avg_salary
      from workers
      group by worker_id) As maxSalary;
```

Comment: this selects the highest avg salary but it doesn't state which is the WorkerID assigned to. Use this to add the IDs also [Maximum of averages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439627/maximum-of-averages)

Answer (score 3):

```
select worker_id, avgsal 
from 
(
  select worker_id, avg(salary) as avgsal 
  from workers 
  group by worker_id
) 
where avgsal=(select  max(avgsal) 
              from (select worker_id, avg(salary) as avgsal 
                    from workers group by worker_id))
```

This will display the highest average along with worker id

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/77676)
you can use

```
SELECT worker_id, AVG(salary)
FROM workers
GROUP BY worker_id
HAVING AVG(salary) = (SELECT MAX(AVG(salary)) FROM workers GROUP BY worker_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select worker_id, avg(salary)
from workers
group by worker_id
having avg(salary) = (select max(avgsal) from 
(select worker_id, avg(salary) as avgsal 
from workers 
group by worker_id));
```

This should also work i guess

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the query by adding a column alias to the column within the sub-query, like so:

```
select max(avg_salary)
from (select worker_id, avg(salary) avg_salary
      from workers
      group by worker_id);
```

However, if `worker_id` uniquely identifies records on the workers table, this is functionally equivalent to (can be simplified to):

```
select max(salary) from workers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(a.high)Avg_highest_salary,
       e.dept 
from  (
    select avg(salary) high,dept from emp group by dept) a,
    emp e 
where  a.dept = e.dept
group by   e.dept
order by   max(a.high) desc
```

It will show the **high Average highest salary first with dept**

If you **don't** want to show the **Salary with Dept** then you can use this

```
select max(avg(salary)) max_avg_salary
from emp
group by dept;
```

Answer (score 0):

using WITH clause it can be done as

```
with averagesal as (
select dept_id d_id, avg(sal) avgsal from emp_details group by dept_id)
select * from averagesal where avgsal = (select max(avgsal) from averagesal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can in this way that the first row is sorted in descending based on average find

```
select top 1  worker_id, avg(salary) as avgsalary 
      from workers
      group by worker_id 
      order by avgsalary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Dep_name
from 
(
  select Dep_name , avg(Salary) as avgsal 
  from salary
  group by Dep_name
) sal1
where avgsal=(select  max(avgsal) 
              from (select Dep_name , avg(salary) as avgsal 
                    from salary group by Dep_name) sal2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following approach:

```
select avg(salary) as max_avg_salary from Salaries group by emp_no order by avg(salary) desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050885/12190487   shows the folllowing error

```
ER_DERIVED_MUST_HAVE_ALIAS: Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Use alias for the new formed column you are selecting from

```
select max(avg_salary)
from (select worker_id, avg(salary) AS avg_salary
      from workers
      group by worker_id) as avg ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me.

```
from (select avg(salary) AS avg_salary
       from employees
      group by Name) AS T;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select avg(sal) over (partition by deptno ) avrg,deptno from emp
order by avrg desc) where rownum<2;
```

Try the above one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to also get the worker_id, inspired by previous answers:

```
SELECT worker_id, MAX(avg_salary)
FROM (SELECT worker_id, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
      FROM workers
      GROUP BY worker_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this with a single `select` statement (combining both `max` and `avg`) like this

```
select max(avg(salary)) max_avg_salary
from workers
group by worker_id;
```