# Find maximum average in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get the maximum average salary and i am using this:

```
select max (avg_salary)
from (select name, avg(salary) AS avg_salary
  from employee
  group by name);
```

But is another way to get same result without using subquery?

Comment: Why do you not want to use subqueries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find maximum avg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050854/how-to-find-maximum-avg)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The solution to that question is the query posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(salary)
FROM employee
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One other option would be:

```
SELECT name, avg(salary) AS avg_salary
FROM employee
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
SELECT name, 
       avg(salary) AS avg_salary   
FROM employee 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY DESC avg_salary 
      LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... this sort desc of avg salary then apply limit

```
SELECT AVG(salary),name
FROM employee GROUP BY name
ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

All employees:

```
SELECT name, 
       AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
FROM employee 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY avg_salary DESC
```

Maximum of one employee:

```
SELECT name, 
AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
FROM employee 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY avg_salary DESC 
LIMIT 1
```