# calculate highest salary department in SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

Question: sql query to get:

The names of the departments with the highest average salary of their employees.

Comment: Wow, you could not type that text? Please, not as an image. Secondly, *you* should write query. When you have a problem, ask about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050854/how-to-find-maximum-avg

Comment: are you using t-sql MS-SQL ?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using t-sql (MS-SQL)

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS 'avgSalary' , dept
 FROM emp
GROUP BY dept
Order BY avgSalary DESC
```