# Write a query to display the highest average obtained from the students.Give an alias as avg_mark. Round the result to 2 decimal places

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiibR.jpg)

Data in Mark table:

```
Value  Subject_ID  Student_ID
------ ----------- ------------
  91        1         1
  90        2         1
  90        3         1
 100        4         9
  67        5         9
  80        5         4
  90        4         4
```

I have tried the query:

```
select round(avg(value),2) as avg_mark 
from Mark;
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGDec.png)

I have tried the following code, it executes successfully and gives the desired result, however it fails to clear test case and IDK why?

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). It's not clear what the expected output is. Also please don't use txtspk abbreviations, like "IDK". Consider that the assignment may be to obtain the average mark of each individual student, and then find the highest one of those.

Comment: Related [How to find maximum avg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050854/how-to-find-maximum-avg)

Answer (score 0):

select max(round(avg(value), 2)) avg_mark from mark group by student_id;